# Sorting list of lists in Python

Tags: list, python-3.x

folks!
I have a list of lists (actually, imported from PostgreSQL as JSON) that looks like this:

```
[{'person_name': 'FRAUDSTER_3', 'score': 10.33}, {'person_name': 'FRAUDSTER_5', 'score': 10.11}, {'person_name': 'FRAUDSTER_2', 'score': 10.44}, {'person_name': 'FRAUDSTER_4', 'score': 10.22}, {'person_name': 'FRAUDSTER_1', 'score': 10.55}]
```

Is there is a neat way to sort it by 'score' value using list.sort or sorted? Probably, lowest score first so I can use pop to get N records with maximum score first.

Comment: Important to note that what you have is a list of dictionaries, not a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sorted(yourlist, key=lambda x:x['score'])
```

Comment: That's not how you access mappings in a dictionary.  You mean `key=lambda x: x['score']` Default sort order is small -> large

Comment: @Patrick Haugh, @Muposat: This is what I was searching for! `scoredict = sorted(scoredict, key=lambda x: x['score'])` and then `print(scoredict.pop())` as many times, as I need. Thanks, folks!

Comment: Answer corrected, thank you @Patrick Haugh

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what you have is a list of dictionaries. You can then use `operator.itemgetter` to sort it:

```
In [362]: L = [{'person_name': 'FRAUDSTER_3', 'score': 10.33}, {'person_name': 'FRAUDSTER_5', 'score': 10.11}, {'person_name': 'FRAUDSTER_2', 'score': 10.44}, {'person_name': 'FRAUDSTER_4', 'score': 10.22}, {'person_name': 'FRAUDSTER_1', 'score': 10.55}]

In [363]: L.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('score'))

In [364]: [i['score'] for i in L]
Out[364]: [10.11, 10.22, 10.33, 10.44, 10.55]
```